# Can't update anything after removing lxde. Error appears

Tags: server, lxde, lxdm

```
sudo apt-get upgrade fails with this error:
Removing lxdm (0.5.3-1) ...
update-rc.d: error: no runlevel symlinks to modify, aborting!
dpkg: error processing package lxdm (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
lxdm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Ubuntu server 16.04.1

Can't remove lxdm, other updates fail to install, have 66 ATM, including security ones.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get -f install` then `sudo apt-get autoremove`,
let me know what you get.

Comment: Looks like `/etc/init.d/lxdm` was corrupted. Could you please remove it (`sudo rm -f /etc/{init,rc?}.d/*lxdm`) and then try to remove `lxdm` with `sudo apt-get remove -f lxdm`. Does that work or are there more errors?

Comment: Nothing above helped.

Comment: Worth to mention that my server was updated to 16.04 from 14.10, and startup scripts are no longer handled by init.d, i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lxdm
```

And then, if that succeeds :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge lxdm
```